# php for() function not looking through variables

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to create pagination links my issue is my php for() function does not seem to be looping through as it should. 
My code is

```
  <?php
     $pagLink = "<div class='pagination'>";
     for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
       {  
          $pagLink .= "<a href='./bloglist?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
       };  
     echo $pagLink . "</div>"; 
  ?>
```

$1 holds a value of 1   and $total_pages I confirmed holds a value of 3 so I am expecting to see a link that says 1 and a link that says 2 on the page but instead it just shows 1 which means its only looping through 1 time and it should be looping through two times.

what am I missing?

Comment: ` };` turn on error reporting. Your PHP looks like it wouldn't even parse.

Comment: @bassxzero the `;` in the end of loops is okay, it does not throw any errors, just like when you have double semi-columns `;;` it does not show any error. (at least in the 5.6 version of PHP)

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Everything seems OK in your code.

Comment: @Arno I agree, I flagged the question, makes us looks like fools lol

Comment: If `$total_pages` is set to 3 as you say, this code works as intended.

Comment: Working demo of your exact code: https://3v4l.org/g4Sgd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried it with the change of double quotes and single quotes and it works fine

```
$pagLink = '<div class="pagination">';
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
{  
    $pagLink .= '<a href="./bloglist?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';  
}  
echo $pagLink . '</div>';
```

Here's the result for a total page of 10;

```
<div class="pagination">
<a href="./bloglist?page=1">1</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=2">2</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=3">3</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=4">4</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=5">5</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=6">6</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=7">7</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=8">8</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=9">9</a>
<a href="./bloglist?page=10">10</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Inversion of double quotes by single quotes does not change the working of the for() loop

Comment: Yes, but it does for the output of the loop which looks more like HTML!

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to define the `$total_pages` variable.
Try this code :

```
<?php
     $pagLink = "<div class='pagination'>";
     $total_pages = 3;
     for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
       {  
          $pagLink .= "<a href='./bloglist?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
       };  
     echo $pagLink . "</div>"; 
  ?>
```

Comment: So you'll always have 3 pages ? no matter what :D, why the loop then, just do a copy/past in HTML!